# Bulk write in mongoDB using vertx

Tags: java, mongodb, vert.x

I am using BulkWriteWithOptions for inserting multiple documents in DB. I want the inserted documents so that I can know which one was inserted, failed or duplicate document.
Following is the piece of code I am using

```
mongoClient.bulkWriteWithOptions(collection, operations, options, repoAsyncResult -> {
                    if (repoAsyncResult.failed()) {

                        LOGGER.error("Bulk insertion failed : {}", repoAsyncResult.cause().getMessage());
                        if(repoAsyncResult.cause() instanceof MongoBulkWriteException ){
                            MongoBulkWriteException exception = (MongoBulkWriteException)repoAsyncResult.cause() ;
                            exception.getWriteErrors().forEach(error -> {
                                LOGGER.error("Insert Error : " + error.getMessage());
                            });
                        }
                        repoFuture.fail(repoAsyncResult.cause());

                    } else {
                        LOGGER.info("Bulk insertion successful : {}", repoAsyncResult.result().toJson());
                        repoFuture.complete(repoAsyncResult.result().toJson());
                    }
                });
```

Is there any way to get the inserted documents as a result?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only get the IDs of upserted documents from `repoAsyncResult.result().getUpserts()` (a `List<JsonObject>` whose `.getAsString("_id")` will return the upserted IDs.)